# Orbeon: getting all input fields to display

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I'm trying to use Orbeon 3.9 CE to create an editor for XML documents.  I've hit a problem in that the xforms fields I've created for the various attributes don't show up in the web form if the existing input XML document does not have them.  I've searched Stack Overflow and the Orbeon doc and wiki but haven't been able to find a setting to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is implemented according to the specification: if the `ref` resolves to an empty sequence (or "empty nodeset" in the XPath 1.0 parlance used by the XForms 1.1 spec), [then the control is considered non-relevant](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms11/#ui-processing). There is no provision for having the node created automatically if missing. So this would need to be done either:

1. Outside of XForms, in a phase of pre-precessing of the XML to add missing element or attributes.
2. In XForms, after the instance is loaded, by [inserting nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms11/#action-insert) in the instance as appropriate.

Unless you need to add just a few nodes, the first option is most likely more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks; I'll try the first option if I continue with Orbeon.

Answer (score 1):

@avernet's response is correct.

Somebody asked a similar question on [this thread](http://orbeon-forms-ops-users.24843.n4.nabble.com/Missing-mandatory-field-elements-td4469324.html).

The recommendation I made was to create an XBL component to handle this automatically. I suggested a [first version of such a component](https://gist.github.com/2156397), more as a suggestion than as a final, usable solution. But that might help you.

Comment: @ebruchez It's possible to change all the default XBL components to add this behavior?

Comment: Yes it's possible (few things aren't), but maybe not desirable. This should at least be an optional behavior. If so, it should probably be a native and configurable feature of the XForms engine.

Comment: @ebruchez This feature is already in Orbeon RoadMap? If not, can I create a feature request in Github? This is vital to my application and I would like to help.

Comment: Sure, you can create an RFE on github!